# UITableView runtime crash

Tags: ios, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"myCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    

NSArray *allSections =[self.tableDataSource allKeys];
NSArray *aSection = [self.tableDataSource objectForKey:[allSections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
NSMutableDictionary *item = [aSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;

if (cell == nil) {

    /* Trace 1 */
    NSLog(@"Init: Section: %i - Row: %i", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

    UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];  
    [mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [mySwitch setOn:NO animated:NO];
    cell.accessoryView = mySwitch;
    cell.accessoryView.tag = [[item objectForKey:@"ID"] integerValue];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"Name"];
    [item setObject:cell forKey:@"cell"];

} else {

    /* Trace 2 */
    NSLog(@"Done: Section: %i - Row: %i", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
    cell = [item objectForKey:@"cell"];

}

return cell;}
```

Hello all,

I'm struggling with a UITableView + accessories which is crashing "sometime" at runtime. The main code  tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath is just above and, as far as I understand, is really based on the standard pattern for a UITableView.

My dataSource is small, it's just a 2 sections dataset, one of 6 lines and another is only 2 lines. All the methods about number of rows in section and number of sections are implemented.

User interface in IB has the required connections and actually everything is working fine. The UITableView in IB is slightly smaller the the main view (there is 2 buttons below the tableview). When I run the app, I can see in the view the first 6 rows (first section), but the last 2 rows (second section) are hidden. Of course, if I scroll down, last 2 rows will appear ...

The issue is when I reduce the UITableView outlet size in IB. If the outlet displays only 2 or 3 rows from the first section at runtime, then the App will crash if I scroll down. The crash will occur at the first row of the second section. Only change with the previous situation is the IB outlet size, nothing has been changed in the code.

Error message in the console is :

*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UITableView.m:5678
2011-07-04 02:08:46.713 iWiR Client[95362:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

If you look at the code, you will see that there is 2 NSLog traces. Normal behavior for the code is that "Trace 1" will be displayed in the console for the first display of the row, and then, if I scroll up and down, that will be "trace 2". This is what the case if the IBoutlet of the UITableView is "big enough", but, as I said, if I reduce the size of the outlet, console will display "Trace 2" even for the first display of the row.

I hope these (long) explanations are clear enough, and tks a bunch for your help ...

Cheers,
Pierre

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a table view with 6 rows out of which 2 rows are visible. As you scroll down to get the 4th row onto the visible region, `cell` that you dequeued from the table view will not be `nil` so the `else` clause will be executed.

```
cell = [item objectForKey:@"cell"];
```

At this point there is not object set for the key `cell`. So `objectForKey:` will return `nil` and cell will be `nil` which you return at the end of the method. This is the reason for the error that  says `'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'` as you are returning `nil` here.

You are not reusing cells via mechanism provided by `UITableView`. Your method should more be like,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSArray *allSections =[self.tableDataSource allKeys];
    NSArray *aSection = [self.tableDataSource objectForKey:[allSections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    NSMutableDictionary *item = [aSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [item objectForKey:@"cell"];    

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Init: Section: %i - Row: %i", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];

        [..]
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hello Deepak, you are 100% right, I did the change and of course it works well !!! Shame on me ... I was to focused on the IB Size issue, and paid not enough attention to the code ...